# Сжатие в javascript разжатие в django/python

Tags: javascript, python, django, сжатие, compression

Необходимо передать большую строку с клиента на сервер. Хочу чтобы она сжималась на клиенте с помощью javascript и разжималась на сервере с помощью django/python.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.
Какой алгоритм архивации есть и там и там?

Comment: В интернете есть lzw алгоритмы сжатия. Оно не сильное, но быстрое. Надо не забывать, что html текстовый формат, и при сложных алгоритмах прийдётся использовать base64 что утяжелит данные.

Comment: Может вам поискать библиотеку gzip сжатия страницы. Многие браузеры поддерживат gzip-пакованые страницы.

Comment: lzw нет готового для python3

Comment: а зачем base64? я копирую dom в текстовом виде, как строку, и хочу его передать на сторонний сервер чтобы там уже распарсить и взять что нужно

Comment: Потому что если вы хотите реализовать сжатие "вручную" - то могут возникнуть проблемы, если сжатая информация будет содержать такие символы, которые браузер не поймёт либо служебные.

Comment: Почитайте тут http://seo-mayak.com/sozdanie-bloga/skorost-zagruzki/kak-vklyuchit-gzip-szhatie-i-uskorit-sajt.html может поможет.

Comment: Насколько большую-то? Может, сжимать вообще смысла нет?

Comment: исходный код страницы целиком, короче говоря dom